# Tree-like layouts in Org-Mode

Tags: emacs, org-mode

Say I want to **enter** information in an Org file that could be **displayed** in a  tree-like format. Can Org help me with this?

For example I want Org to display a hierarchy of entities as follows:

```
ROOT
├── foo
│   └── bar
├── baz
├── bax
├── src
│   ├── main
│   │   ├── java
│   │   │   └── something
│   │   └── fine
│   ├── yes
│   └── no
```

How can I enter this information in a way that Org understands it so that it can render the tree as above?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might be interested by ditaa block for this:

```
#+name: tree
#+begin_src ditaa
  ROOT      
  |
  +--foo
  |  +----bar
  |  
  +--baz   
  +--bax   
  +--src   
  |  +--main
  |  |  +---java
  |  |  |   +---something
  |  |  |
  |  |  +---fine
  |  |
  |  +--yes
  |  +--no
#+end_src
```

typing <kbd>C-c `</kbd> in the src block will put you in artist-mode, a mode made for editing ascii art and that should make editing those tree easier.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming `ROOT` is a title that you would want displayed, you can do something like

```
* ROOT
** foo
*** bar

** baz

** bax

** src
*** main
**** java
***** something

**** fine

*** yes

*** no
```

The empty lines are optional. I just use them for readability.

If you only want to use one asterisk per level, checkout [this](http://orgmode.org/worg/org-tutorials/org-appearance.html#sec-1) link which explains how you can modify `org-mode` to use indentation and a single asterisk.

Comment: Thanks - I guess I knew I could do this already but was looking for more of a tree-like view (no stars, and with vertical & horizontal lines)

Comment: @user815423426 updated answer. There is a way to use a single asterisk + indentation to accomplish the same thing.

Comment: `+1`. Thanks. I will wait a few more days in case anyone there is an alternative solution for it.

Answer (score 2):

If the directory already exists you can use `tree`, as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23989232/is-there-a-way-to-represent-a-directory-tree-in-a-github-readme-md/35889620). I've tried both and had issue with executing ditaa sometimes (emacs couln't find the ditaa.jar in some installations). Furthermore, ditaa output is an image, but the output of tree is text. You can use a `src_block` like this:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC sh :results output :exports results
tree /path/to/dir
#+END_SRC
```