# Tool for creating a static page showing folder structure apache-like (for use in GitLab)

Tags: html, git, apache, gitlab, static-pages

I have some files stored in a web server, which serves the files using apache like this:

[image: ![enter image description here]

Now, I'm planning to move all these folders to a GitLab repository, the problem is that GitLab is slow (please do not offer to use GitHub, I have certainly checked that alternative) and so I don't want to use GitLab's default way of showing files, instead, I want something similar as the apache way of showing files, as a static page, to use it as a GitLab page, so that I would be able to download and see the structure of my repo, but fast.

I wouldn't mind if I have to run a command to produce this static HTML page before each commit I make, but it would be cool to know that it exists, otherwise, I would have to create it (using python, for example), but of course, I would prefer an already created wheel instead of rediscover mine.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You could consider generating a page in markdown, with your Git repo (repository) structure content, and then publish it on the wiki side of your (here GitLab) project.

See "[Is there a way to represent a directory tree in a Github `README.md`?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35889620/6309)" as an example, except you don't want to use your own repo `README.md`, but rather the wiki, in order to keep the repo and its representation (on wiki) independent
.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate your effort, this is useful in some situations, but my project could have thousands of files within just a single folder, so it would not be so easy to manage as a simple folder structure, but I'll consider it if I don't find anything more similar to what I'm looking for, thank you!

Comment: @DarielRudt Then you could still generate a markdown page, this time, one per folder, each one published on the wiki, with a page structure imitating your folder structure.